# What kind of house could someone make in a snow covered desert?

Tags: deserts

I was wondering what types of houses could be established in a desert which has been covered in snow for the last five years.  Wood is somewhat accessible from merchants, and from trips to a neighboring forest, but still somewhat of a hassle.  Also, what types of quick shelters could be established with minimal resources?

Comment: What research have you done so far on this topic? Could you include that in your question?

Comment: Have you ever in your life heard the term Eskimo or igloo?

Comment: Google "ice hotel" or "Harbin ice festival"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is not yet complete I will add more building types.

1. **Igloo:** Compact snow for bricks and build in a dome shape for strength.

   **Pros:** Free materials easy to find and transport. Quite strong  structure. For a house made of snow they are quite warm as long as it is reasonably well sealed.

   **Cons:** Needs multiple people to build. Can melt in summer. If partially melted, they can collapse.

   **Quick note:** For a quick house that can be made by one person dig a hole in a snow hill and seal the entrance. These can be dangerous as powdery snow will collapse.
2. **Tent:** Use a frame of strong, light sticks in a pyramid shape. Bind them together with some sot of string/twine (Can be made from animal remains) Cover this in a tight fitting piece of fur.

   **Pros:** Quick and easy to build. Portable, just untie the poles and wrap them in the fur.

   **Cons:** Can be quite cold, use in summer. Inflammable. Can be damaged quite easily.

Comment: Igloos can be made with limited manpower. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3pd-wxNEKQ  If necessary this can be done by one person.